# ARMA(p,q) model interpreting PACF and ACF

Tags: modeling, arma

[image]

Here I have two time series (ACF, PACF), one on the left and one on the right. I have difficulties interpreting the results. Both PACF/ACF couples look the same and I can't distinguish any geometric decay or cutoff points. Would this be a AR/MA or ARMA model and how many lags would you specify for p and q??

Comment: The left one looks like white noise. The one on the right *might* be reasonably modelled by AR(5), but I'd probably see if there's enough left after an ARMA(1,1) to bother with.

Comment: Thanks ARMA returns a pacf/acf without any red dotes above the blue line. I used this: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/econ/box-jenkins-model-selection.html